# How to pass in a repository object into view model constructor WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

So I am implementing MVVM pattern into my WPF application. Inside of my view model, I have a dependency of a repository object that gets passed in in a constructor:

```
public class RequestListViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private readonly RequestRepository repository;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

        public RequestListViewModel(RequestRepository repository)
        {
            this.repository = repository;
        }
         
    }
```

If I am using data binding in XAML, how do I pass my repository object into my view model? One way is I can just new up a repository and make my view models only have a default constructor, but I want to have the flexibility to switch it out during runtime. Currently, I am using manual dependency injection to wire everything up and I know there is a container I can use but what is stopping from pursing that route is how would the container know when to instantiate the view model?

Thanks!

EDIT: Including manual (poorman) DI:

```
public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);
            var databaseService = new RequestDbContext();
            var addRequest = new AddRequest(databaseService);
            var getAllRequestList = new GetAllRequestList(databaseService);
            var requestRepository = new RequestRepository(getAllRequestList, addRequest);
            var requestListViewModel = new RequestListViewModel(requestRepository);
            Application.Current.MainWindow = new MainWindow(requestListViewModel);
            Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();

        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you create your view models?  Dependency Injection?  Manually?  If you are using DI, then the idea would be to register the `RequestRepository` and then register each ViewModel.  The Dependency Injector would do the rest

Comment: I am instantiating all the dependency in my Application layer, and using the poorman's strategy to wire everything up (please see edit). How would a DI container know when a view model needs to be instantiated?

Comment: A DI Container looks at the required constructor arguments of every object you register.  If you register `RequestRepository` as taking no arguments and then you register `RequestListViewModel` as taking a `RequestRepository` as the only argument in its constructor, then whenever the DI container is asked for an instance of `RequestListViewModel` it's going to use its knowledge of how to create a `RequestRepository` to supply that instance to `RequestListViewModel`.  That's how DI containers work

Comment: @BrendonCheung: How to "pass my repository object into my view model" depends on how and where you instantiate the view model. You cannot do this in XAML.